# SQL non alphabetical order in WHERE IN

Tags: sql, where-clause, alphabetical

Let's say I have this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM product
WHERE name IN ('CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556',
                  'CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877',
                  'NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605',
                  'GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839')
```

the result is:

```
CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556
CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877
GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839
NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605
```

which is ordered by the alphabetical order

How can I get a result order by the index of appearance in the list?

basically I want this as a result:

```
CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556
CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877
NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605
GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: what is your order in the list...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a popular approach to sort things in SQL, so [I've blogged about this example here](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-implement-sort-indirection-in-sql/). You would have to explicitly order by those values in your list, e.g. using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT name
FROM product
WHERE name IN ('CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556',
               'CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877',
               'NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605',
               'GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556' THEN 1
              WHEN name = 'CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877' THEN 2
              WHEN name = 'NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605' THEN 3
              WHEN name = 'GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839' THEN 4
         END
```

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/615d4/1)

If you want to avoid repeating those literals, you could resort to this trick:

```
SELECT product.name
FROM product
JOIN (
  VALUES('CE367FAACDHCANPH-151556', 1),
        ('CE367FAACEX9ANPH-153877', 2),
        ('NI564FAACJSFANPH-162605', 3),
        ('GE526OTACCD3ANPH-149839', 4)
) AS sort (name, sort)
ON product.name = sort.name
ORDER BY sort.sort
```

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/615d4/10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PATINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx). At least if your names have more and less the same structure.

```
SELECT [Name] FROM product 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Name, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Name+'z')-1));
```

Check out this example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c653/2)